# Upgrade sagepay form 2.23 to 3.0

Tags: php, e-commerce, shopping-cart, opayo

I have a few shops that use the sagepay 2.23 form protocols. Sagepay have recently told me they are stopping support for them, so I need to upgrade them. So, I was just wondering if I don't need any new functionality what things will I need to change to move on to protocol 3.
They doesn't seem to be any sort of **upgrade guide**. I have seen the full document and at first glance it looks virtually the same. Any help would be greatly appreciated. 
regards
Glen

Comment: Most of the existing things are the same. Protocol 3 brings new features for you to use. If you are not amending the things you are sending then you should just able able to change the protocol value you post to 3.00 and not have any issues.

Comment: Thanks haxtbh for the response. I did get a mail from them eventually citing this document - which was helpful. So for every one else with the same question you can check this out. 
http://www.sagepay.co.uk/file/10286/download-document/Technical_Guide_to_Update_Sage_Pay_Form_Protocol(2%2023).pdf?token=mqeZ3VOJlnDFkrVLswb1G6vIT-0n_cfamMzqH_c4sI4

Comment: @GlenLockhart it looks like you found the upgrade guide you needed (thanks for that!) You can answer your own question and mark it as accepted, assuming you have enough rep to do that. Otherwise, let me know and I'll answer it for you.

Answer (score 4):

See [this Sage Pay migration guide](http://www.sagepay.co.uk/file/10286/download-document/Technical_Guide_to_Update_Sage_Pay_Form_Protocol(2%2023).pdf?token=mqeZ3VOJlnDFkrVLswb1G6vIT-0n_cfamMzqH_c4sI4) for full answer. Basically, 3.0 works the same as 2.23. You just need to change the protocol value.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @Ben How do you make out that this is not an answer to the question ... is there something wrong with the guide ... I know it's a link which is not ideal but it's surely better to link to it than copying the entire document here.

Answer (score 2):

In a quick view...

**Mandatory Transaction Registration Field Changes**

The VPSProtocol field in **bold** represents the mandatory change that is necessary to be compatible with v3.00 of the Sage Pay Form protocol.

The VPSProtocol, TxType, and Vendor fields are the only fields not part of the Crypt field, indicated by the grey background colour, while the remainder of the XML will be sent encrypted.

**VPSProtocol=3.00**&TxType=PAYMENT&Vendor=tonestest&VendorTxCode=tonestest-
1394184637894-393502&Amount=31.35&Currency=GBP&Description=The best DVDs from
tonestest&SuccessURL=http://integrationkits.cloudapp.net/javakit/form/success/&FailureURL=http://integrationkits.cloudapp.net/javakit/form/failure/&BillingSurname=Surname&BillingFirstnames=Fname
Mname&BillingAddress1=BillAddress Line 1&BillingCity=BillCity&BillingPostCode=W1A
1BL&BillingCountry=GB&DeliverySurname=Surname&DeliveryFirstnames=Fname
Mname&DeliveryAddress1=BillAddress Line
1&DeliveryCity=BillCity&DeliveryPostCode=W1A
1BL&DeliveryCountry=GB&CustomerName=Fname Mname
Surname&CustomerEMail=customer@example. com&SendEMail=1&eMailMessage=Thanks for
your order&BillingAddress2=BillAddress Line 2&BillingPhone=44 (0)7933 000
000&DeliveryAddress2=BillAddress Line 2&DeliveryPhone=44 (0)7933 000
000&Basket=2:Shaolin
Soccer:3:8.29:1.66:9.95:29.85:Delivery:1:1.50:0:1.50:1.50&AllowGiftAid=0&ApplyAVS
CV2=0&Apply3DSecure=0

**Mandatory Sage Pay Response Field Changes**

The **BankAuthCode**, **DeclineCode**, and **ExpiryDate** fields in **bold** represent the mandatory changes that are necessary to be compatible with v3.00 of the Sage Pay Form protocol.

All of the example fields will be returned as part of the Crypt field.

VendorTxCode=tonestest-1394184637894-393502&VPSTxId={9CA3B265-9FDF-E550-7565-
62678E44A7B8}&Status=OK&StatusDetail=0000 : The Authorisation was
Successful.&TxAuthNo=6529795&AVSCV2=SECURITY CODE MATCH
ONLY&AddressResult=NOTMATCHED&PostCodeResult=NOTMATCHED&CV2Result=MATCHED&GiftAid
=0&3DSecureStatus=OK&CAVV=00000101147993000000000000000000&CardType=VISA&Last4Dig
its=0000&Amount=33.85**&DeclineCode=00&BankAuthCode=999777&ExpiryDate=1215**

Comment: Actually the biggest bit of the job no one has mentioned. I needed to update the encryption method, which took the majority of the time involved. Thanks for the other input guys.

Comment: Hi Glen, Can you provide the encryption algorythm? I am having the same issue and the algorythm I use fails.

Comment: @mev9669 - this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28525026/sage-pay-v3-00-integration